# изменения в файле Graddle проекта

Tags: android, gradle

Нужно добавить зависимость в файл Graddle. Именно в файл проекта. Но он изменился и не понятно куда добавлять зависимость. Вот старый файл [image: old file]

А вот новый
[image: new file]
Подскажите как теперь добавлять зависимость?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикладывайте текстовую информацию не скриншотами, а в виде текста, чтобы ее можно было копировать и чтобы работал поиск.

Answer (score 0):

В новом формате buildscript-зависимости добавляются в виде [плагинов](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) по их идентификатору.

Например, если вы хотите добавить в свой проект плагин [navigation safeargs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args), то нужно добавить его в секцию `plugins` родительского модуля:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.2' apply false
}
```

И применить плагин в секции `plugins` модуля `app`:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
```